# Animate Presence exit not working framer motion

Tags: reactjs, exit, framer-motion, unmount

Animate presence **exit** prop is not working

what i am doing wrong?

```js
<AnimatePresence>
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, x: "-100%" }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, x: "100%" }}>
        <h1>Head</h1>
      </motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

**Fixed!!**

Fixed it by adding these two props to Switch:

import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();

```
<Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
//Routes
</Switch>
```

Comment: Are you saying the exit animation isn't working between page transitions? Or are you *just* trying to move a div from left to right?

Comment: i am working with react router to switch among other components

Comment: If you're switching between routes, you have to set `exitBeforeEnter` on the AnimatePresence to let the previous page animate out first - https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animatepresenceprops.exitbeforeenter

Comment: **Note:** `exitBeforeEnter` has been deprecated and replaced with `mode="wait"` - https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/###mode

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The reason that this is not working is that you have to explicitly specify the key of the child that you are conditionally rendering.

Doc reference: https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#unmount-animations

In your case that is the `<motion.div>`

I have some examples of AnimatePresense here

- With Multiple Items: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-multiple-item-animation-presence-sdmq2
- With React Router: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-react-router-transition-kczeg

Comment: second sandbox helped me! thank you @Joshua Wootonn

Comment: Dude you literally saved me from my Headache thanks so much

Comment: The sandbox has broken unfortunately : (

Comment: Thanks for saying something @SaroGFX. CodeSandbox auto-updated framer motion to the latest version without auto-updating the react version. Since Framer Motion 7 requires React 18 the sandboxes were broken. I just downgraded the framer motion, and they are working again. 

Note: This doesn't conflict with any breaking changes in framer-motion 7, so if you are on the latest it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me solve my issue as well :)

Comment: Why on earth does the first example of their documentation not have the key property set!