# Router location navigator typescript, react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I use TS and now i have to  put stuff in my Router and I don't know what.

index.js:

```
import { Router, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

const location = useLocation()
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router location={????????} navigator={?????????} >
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes >
          <Route path="/"                           element={<Home           />} />
          <Route path="Portfolio/:portfolioId"      element={<SingleShooting />} />
           ...
        </Routes>
      
    </>
  );
}
```

WHat do I have to put in?

*Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RouterProps': location, navigatorts(2739)*

(I want to do this, because of this:
[Animate Presence exit not working framer motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67974970/animate-presence-exit-not-working-framer-motion))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [React-Router official docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router), you should avoid using `Router` directly. Instead, use `BrowserRouter` or `StaticRouter`(server rendering)
And also, As you are going to do *Animate Presence exit not working framer motion*, You may need to use `Routes` instead of `Switch` in case you are using `React-Router-Dom` v6.

```
<Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
    // Your routes in here
    <Route path="/"                           element={<Home           />} />
    <Route path="Portfolio/:portfolioId"      element={<SingleShooting />} />
</Routes>
```

Edit to fix your commit

In your index.tsx

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
     <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Comment: i  did import {  BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";  when I use `location={location}` i have do define `location`. Therefore i used it in a wrong way. but i got the solution of it - thx

Comment: Yes, All good, @Spluli

Comment: now i get this error `Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Comment: Updated answer, @Spluli, it is because you are trying to use `useLocation` outside of `BrowserRouter`, useLocation should be used inside of it. You may need to Wrap `App` with `BrowserRouter` since you are using `useLocation` in the `App`'s body

Comment: I see my issue: i just had  to change  `import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';` to `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';`    thx :)

Comment: The principle is simple, if you know it. You are welcome! @Spluli XD

Answer (score 1):

1. file extension for typescript should be .tsx, not js.
2. Remove location and router from index.tsx so leave it as its original file:

```
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
      document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement,
    );
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
    );
    
    reportWebVitals();
```

3. Router setup should be like so:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={< Home />} />
        <Route path="Portfolio/:portfolioId" element={< SingleShooting />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i have tsx, :) just did a mistake by writing. got the Router as you do

Comment: now i get this error `Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Comment: I see my issue: i just had to change import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'; to import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';